# DBT: Looping in DBT

Tags: dbt

Requirement: To convert snowflake statement into dbt model

Below is the statement , I am trying figure out how to do Loop in DBT Model , tried sql with cross with dev.abc but count was not matching

```
DECLARE
    cur_col CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        col_name
    FROM
        dev.abc;

    my_cur_col VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
    FOR RECORD IN cur_col DO my_cur_col:= RECORD.col_name;
INSERT INTO
    dev.results (
        coh_type,
        coh,
        cust,
        so_ls,
        si_ls
    )
SELECT
    :my_cur_col AS coh_type,
    identifier(:my_cur_col) AS coh,
    COUNT(DISTINCT account) AS cust,
    SUM(so_ls) AS so_ls,
    SUM(si_ls) AS si_ls
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        LENGTH(num_empl) AS emp_d,
        LENGTH(ann_rev) AS ann_rev_d
    FROM
        dev.facts
    WHERE rev > 0
    ) AS A
    GROUP BY1,2,3;
    END FOR;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach for this use case would be:

1. Create a source model that selects the list of columns:

```sql
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

select 
  col_name
from dev.abc
```

2. Then in your main model, loop over the columns and UNION ALL the queries:

```sql
{% set columns = source('column_source', 'dev') %}

{% for col in columns %}

select
  {{ col }} as coh_type,
  identifier({{ col }}) as coh,
  count(distinct account) as cust,
  sum(so_ls) as so_ls,
  sum(si_ls) as si_ls

from dev.facts
where rev > 0
group by 1,2,3

{% if not loop.last %}
UNION ALL
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

3. Materialize the model into a table:

```sql
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

{% set query %}
...loop query...
{% endset %}

{{ run_query(query) }}
```

Comment: Thanks i didnot understand step 3 , should those be in step 2 you meant ?

Comment: why need all those cursor and looping staff?
just cross join the one column abc table with the aggregated facts table..

Answer (score 0):

dbt loop docs:

1. [Here](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/using-jinja?step=5) if you need it from the predefined list
2. [Here](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/using-jinja?step=8) if you need it from the table results

Your case falls into the (2). You can create the following dbt model:

```sql
{{ config(materialized='table' }}

{% set payment_methods_query %}
    SELECT col_name FROM dev.abc
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(payment_methods_query) %}

{% if execute %}
    {% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
    {% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}

{% for my_cur_col in results_list %}

    SELECT
        {{ my_cur_col }} AS coh_type,
        identifier({{ my_cur_col }}) AS coh,
        COUNT(DISTINCT account) AS cust,
        SUM(so_ls) AS so_ls,
        SUM(si_ls) AS si_ls
    FROM dev.facts
    WHERE rev > 0
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3

    {% if not loop.last %}
        UNION ALL
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Notes:

1. Consider using native SQL functionality instead of looping. If you already have a table in the database you can use `JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`
2. `my_cur_col` doesn't change anything. It looks like you are trying to do the cohort analysis and I guess you need to filter something by the value in `my_cur_col`, otherwise it just duplicates `dev.facts`. Basically, you are doing `CROSS JOIN` via `CURSOR`. Most probably you are trying to achieve something else
3. I hardcoded `dev.abc` and `dev.facts` for simplicity, consider using `{{ source() }}` instead